# modify number of variables in istringstream

Tags: c++, istringstream, sstream

I need to get input in a line based on a modifiable number of variables that are determined from an earlier input.

If the input you get in an earlier function is 1, the the code would be like

```
std::string istring;
std::getline(std::cin, istring);
std::istringstream stream(istring);
while (stream >> a)
{
   statement;
}
```

is it possible to make a condition for while loop that changes depending on what your input is ? so that if the input was for example 5, it would behave like

```
while (stream >> a >> a >> a >> a >> a)
{
   statement;
}
```

I tried doing `while ((stream>>a)*number)` but that doesn't work

Comment: Do you have to use `istringstream`? Because you could also just create an array of strings like: `std::vector<std::string> istring` and use `std::getline` in a for loop.

Comment: There should be multiple variables of input in each line. Earlier the program asks for the number of people it will take info about, so if that number is for example 3, then each line should look like "1 2 3" or "3 4 5" and so on. The number of lines is arbitrary but the number of variables in each line depends of number of people determined from earlier input

Comment: I hope you don't actually have `a` 5 times in that statement, and you instead have different variables there ?

Comment: Actually, from what I can tell, there's no difference in the program's behavior whether it's (stream>>a>>a>>a) or (stream>>a>>b>>c)... but that wasn't what was troubling me

Comment: Let's imagine the earlier input was "5". Then how should `istringstream` know where the input for one variable ends and the input for the next variable starts? Is there any kind of delimiter?

Comment: A blank space is what delimits the variables. So if the input was 5 "1 23 4 56 789" would be valid input , but "1 2 3 4 5 6" wouldn't

Comment: yes, actually, I understand what you're saying, to work with the variables further in the program you can't have them all be a, but just in terms of the input stream and checking the condition it does the same thing. but either way, the problem here isn't how to make a stream take in a set number of variables, it's how to make it take in a number that changes depending on input

Comment: @SanderDeDycker The sequence point argument does not apply here. As long as the `a` is just a variable, the order of operations is well-defined. Remember, the `<<` expand to nested function calls underneath, which have to be executed in a fixed order. The only thing that is left undefined is the order of evaluation of the arguments to those calls, but since you pass the variable `a` directly, no evaluation of arguments is needed. The fact that you reuse the same variable for multiple function calls here does not change that.

Answer (score 3):

## Specific Solution

First to answer your specific question:

> I need to get input in a line based on a modifiable number of variables that are determined from an earlier input.

The solution in C++ to that is a combination of a `istringstream`, a `while` loop and a `vector`:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <sstream>
#include <vector>

int main() {

    unsigned int earlierInput = 5;  // this is the earlier input
    std::vector<int> numbers;  // The type of vector also controls what
                               // data type you want the user to give
                               // you. Because the stream will try to
                               // the user input into that type.

    while (numbers.size() != earlierInput) {

        // Here we ask the user for input and convert the input
        // to a stream, like that we can try to convert the user
        // input into the data type we want.
        std::string istring;
        std::cout << "Please type in " << earlierInput << " numbers: ";
        std::getline(std::cin, istring);
        std::istringstream reader(istring);

        // read as many numbers as possible.
        for (int number; reader >> number;) {
            numbers.push_back(number);
        }

        if (numbers.size() != earlierInput) {
            // if not enough numbers empty vector and print
            // error message
            std::cout << "Not the right amount of numbers!";
            std::cout << "Try again!" << std::endl;
            numbers.clear();
        }
    }

    // If we get here the user typed in the right amount of numbers
    std::cout << "You typed the following numbers:" << std::endl;
    for (const int& i : numbers) {
        std::cout << i << std::endl;
    }
}
```

This is for exactly one user input. If you want to ask the user an arbitrary amount of times to do this (e.g you want to ask the user 10 times for 5 numbers), then you need to apply the rule above again and as such stack up:

```
    #include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <sstream>
#include <vector>

int main() {

    unsigned int amountOfInputs = 2;  // this is the amount of times
                                      // you want the user to type
                                      // something in
    unsigned int earlierInput = 5;  // this is the earlier input


    std::vector<std::vector<int>> allNumbers; // Now we need a vector in
                                // a vector to store the results.
                                // The type of the inner vector also
                                // controls what data type you want the
                                // user to give you.

    while (allNumbers.size() != amountOfInputs) {
        std::vector<int> numbers; // This is the vector as in the example
                                  // above.

        while (numbers.size() != earlierInput) {
            // Here we ask the user for input and convert the input
            // to a stream, like that we can try to convert the user
            // input into the data type we want.
            std::string istring;
            std::cout << "Please type in " << earlierInput << " numbers: ";
            std::getline(std::cin, istring);
            std::istringstream reader(istring);

            // read as many numbers as possible.
            for (int number; reader >> number;) {
                numbers.push_back(number);
            }

            if (numbers.size() != earlierInput) {
                // if not enough numbers empty vector and print
                // error message
                std::cout << "Not the right amount of numbers!";
                std::cout << "Try again!" << std::endl;
                numbers.clear();
            }
        }

        // If we get here the user typed in the right amount of numbers
        // and we can save them and clear the array for using it again.
        allNumbers.push_back(numbers);
        numbers.clear();
    }

    std::cout << "You typed the following numbers:" << std::endl;
    unsigned int round = 1;
    for (auto numbersOfRound : allNumbers) {
        std::cout << "For round " << round++ << ": ";
        for (auto i: numbersOfRound) {
            std::cout << i;
        }
        std::cout << std::endl;
    }
}
```

## Theory

### Why Vectors

To save an arbitrary amount of data and be able to access it, you must use a dynamic allocated array or anything alike. That is because at compile time you don't know how many variables you will need at runtime and as such you cannot give all of them a name.

### Why streams

In theory a stream is a possibly infinit long string or data (see also [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stream_(computing))). A user input is therefor a `stream` as it may theoretically be infinit long. Though this does not apply in praxis.

To extract informations from a stream one has to use the `>>` operator, also known as the extraction operator. This operator does not support `vectors` as an (rhs) operand as stated in the documentation [here](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/istream/istream/operator%3E%3E/). It supports only basic datatypes (that is why we need a temporary variable `int number` in the examples above).

Comment: I think you misunderstood the problem .The code you wrote takes a number and then later checks if the array size is equal to that number, but it doesn't have to be equal. The only condition is that you enter input for 5 variables each time. How many times you're going to enter a line of input is arbitrary. So if there's 5 people, in the vast majority of cases the array won't end up having 5 variables, but 5xN instead.

Comment: edit: I wrote "the only condition is that you enter input for N variables each time" . N should have been 5 to avoid confusion in relation to what I wrote later. I edited it out

Comment: I think an ever simpler solution would be if the code was like the one you posted earlier , but with an added for loop in the while loop that adds input to the belonging vector[i] spot which is used to add up all the inputs for the particular person. I guess I know what I can do now to make it run, but both solutions are hacky - still no idea how to do this with an input stream. But thx for the effort

Comment: An input stream can divide an input only on whitespaces. So actually you can do something about it. Look at the condition of the while loop above. It is actually doing, what you want.

Comment: you still missed the point. The number of lines is not supposed to be equal to the number of people entered. The number of people is what is used to determine how many variables are entered in each line - one per person. I tried running the code, and what it does is take 5 lines of input where each line can consist of an arbitrary number of variables, whereas it should take an arbitrary number of input lines where each line should consist of 5 variables.

Comment: you don't even need a vector of vectors to solve the problem, since if there's 5 people , then each line consists of 5 variables and therefore adds 1 value per person to that person's overall score. A vector of vector would be needed you had to keep record of what each line was, but since only the overall score for each person matters, an ordinary vector can do the job.

Comment: the only catch in this whole problem is that the number we're referring to as 5 is actually N, determined by how many people there are , and therefore I don't know how to write the condition for the while loop

Comment: This would be the solution to your specific problem. But NOT the answer to your question. You asked for a way for an arbitrary input and that is what I showed you (use vectors and use their size information in while loops). Apparently I also was successful, as you got the idea and now you are even having an idea how to apply it to your specific problem.

Comment: I will post a solution for the following: Take an arbitrary amount of inputs, but check if each input has N numbers.

Comment: I asked how to write a condition for the stream to consist of a modifiable number of variables. I have no problem at all writing a loop that takes input from the user N number of times.

Comment: "I will post a solution for the following: Take an arbitrary amount of inputs, but check if each input has N numbers." , well yes, that was the idea the whole time : ) would be cool if you can post that

Comment: @fishyperil: The second example should be what you are looking for in your specific case. Take also a look at the theory behind all that.